# File not found though it's present in the directory

Tags: c, ubuntu, server, shared-memory, proxy-server

I'm trying to implement client-proxy-server. Communication between client and proxy is as usual (HTTP GET). But the communication between proxy server and server is done through shared memory. Whichever file client requested (in this case index.html), proxy server writes it to shared memory. Server reads it from shared memory and through HTTP returns it. Following is proxy code:

```
             //creating shared memory segment
                char c;
                int shmid;
                key_t key;
                char *shm;
               char *s= (char *)malloc (strlen(buffer)+1);
                //naming shared memory segment 5678
                key=5678;
                //creating the segment
                if((shmid =shmget (key,SHMSZ,IPC_CREAT|0666))<0){
                         perror("shmget");
                         exit(1);
                }
                //attaching segment to our dataspace
                if((shm =shmat (shmid,NULL, 0 )) == (char *) -1){
                         perror("shmat");
                         exit(1);
                 }
                //adding data to segment
                s= shm;
               // strcpy(*s,buffer);
               for(int i=0; i<strlen(buffer); i++){
                *s++= buffer[i];
                printf("inside string s %s",s);
}
                *s= NULL;







               //////////////////////////////////////////////
                write(server_fd, "1", sizeof(buffer));  
                fflush(stdout);  


              //waiting for server to write something
              while(*shm!='*')
                    sleep(1);
```

And this is server side

```
           char c;
          int shmid;
          key_t key;
          char *shm;
          char *s= (char *)malloc (strlen(buffer)+1);
          //naming shared memory segment 5678
          key=5678;
          //Locate the segment
          if((shmid =shmget (key,SHMSZ,0666))<0){
               perror("shmget");
               exit(1);
         }
          //attaching the segment
         if((shm =shmat (shmid,NULL,0))==(char *) -1){
               perror("shmat");
               exit(1);

         }
         s =shm;
         printf("File name received is :\n");

         for(s=shm ; *s!=NULL; s++){
               putchar (*s);
         }
         putchar('\n');
         //changing first character of segment to make sure proxy knows that we have read it
         //reading html file
           char mesg[99999], *reqline[3], data_to_send[BYTES], path[99999];
       int rcvd, fd, bytes_read;
           if ( open(s, O_RDONLY)!=-1)    //FILE FOUND// change
                {
                    printf("%s",s);

                    send(c_fd, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17, 0);
                    while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 )
                        write (c_fd, data_to_send, bytes_read);
                }
                else    {write(c_fd, "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n", 23); //FILE NOT FOUND
                                        }

         *shm = '*';
```

The problem is that server is unable to get index.html file this way. It says 404 not found. But when I hardcoded string "index.html", it successfully returned it.

Comment: I would suggest either examining the string you're using for the filename in the debugger, or printing the bytes out as hex to make sure you do not have any extra unprintable characters, like an end of line character.

Comment: There is a null terminator. How can I remove this? & isn't it always present in string even when we hardcode@RetiredNinja